# Firestore: How i can read subcollection data with documentID?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how i can read only current user comments? For "my own comments" page. my code is run, but if ( where field : currentuid ) is not exist not print("no data"). only  print ("documents.data()")

```
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("tweets").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        for document in snapshot!.documents {
            self.db.collection("tweets").document(document.documentID).collection("comments").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: self.uid).getDocuments(completion: { (snapshot2, error2) in
                for document2 in snapshot2!.documents {
                    print("\(document2.documentID) -> \(document2.data())")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.collection("tweets").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    for document in snapshot!.documents {
        self.db.collection("tweets").document(document.documentID).collection("comments")
          .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: self.uid).getDocuments(completion: { (snapshot2, error2) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                if snapshot2.isEmpty {
                    print("No comments from \(self.uid) found")
                } else {
                    for document2 in snapshot2!.documents {
                        print("\(document2.documentID) -> \(document2.data())")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Note that work is underway on collection group queries, which would allow you to do the above with a single query across all collections named `comments`.